# http rewrite not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I tried to write rewrite url for my use case. but it was not working.

Sample user end url:

http://frontend1.techdev.local/user1/app/stats/info.png?t=1234

based on Request URI, it needs to redirect the request to different backend server.

For example,

Flow 1:
http://frontend1.techdev.local/user1/app/stats/info.png?t=1234
Redirect to 
http://app1.techdev.local/user1/app/stats/qwezzsdew.png?t=1234

Flow 2:
http://frontend1.techdev.local/user1/app/html5/qweqwrw.png?t=12345
redirect to 
http://app1.techdev.local/newuser/app/html5/qweqwrw.png?t=12345

Flow 3:
http://frontend1.techdev.local/usr1/app/code1/123455.png?t=12345
redirect to 
http://app1.techdev.local/newuser/app/code1/qweqwrw.png?t=12345

I started to test the rule with first one,, Even that too not working.

```
RewriteRule "^/user1/app/stats/(.*)$" "http://app1.techdev.local/user1/app/stats/$1 [L]"
```

can someone please help on this

Comment: Could you enable and post the debug logs for the rewrite module ([RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) for apache 2.2,
[LogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) for apache 2.4) ?

Comment: What does "not working" mean - what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user1/app/stats/(.*) http://app1.techdev.local/user1/app/stats/qwezzsdew.png [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^user1/app/html5/(.*) http://app1.techdev.local/newuser/app/html5/qweqwrw.png [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^usr1/app/code1/(.*) http://app1.techdev.local/newuser/app/code1/qweqwrw.png [QSA,L]
```

Not sure if the `usr1` in your last example is meant to be `user`?

QSA = query string append, so parameters like ?t=12345 will be appended to the target.